# Use SensioFrameworkExtraBundle and Web Debug Toolbar in Symfony2

Tags: symfony

I am using the SensioFrameworkExtraBundle located here http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/index.html to allow for routes and template information to be placed directly above controller actions like:

```
/**
* @Route("/")
* @Template()
*/
public function indexAction($name = 'test'){

return array('name' => $name);

}
```

This causes the framework to pass the returned array to a template located in the views folder with the name index.html.twig.

It also prevents the need to include the `Response` class in your controller.

The trouble is, this also prevents the `web debug toolbar` from displaying.

Is there anyway to use the SensioFrameworkExtraBundle in this manner and still have the web debug toolbar display?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's the annotation that's the problem. Is your view extending app/Resources/base.html.twig (or .php)? I've seen that when my views don't extend the base I don't see the web debug toolbar.

Comment: Looks like you either have to return a response or extend the base template. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The web debug toolbar is placed just before the `</body>`.

So you can use `twig`, `Response` or anything you want, if the final HTML has `<body></body>` then the web debug toolbar will be automatically placed.

Hope this helps.